# Determine when an image has loaded in svg with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to work out how to determine when an svg image has loaded in the browser. I'm using Raphael JS and I've tried:

```
var image = paper.image(path, 0,0,10,10);
image.node.addEventListener('load', function(){alert("test");});
```

and:

```
$('image').on('load')
```

all to no avail. I've also used "onload" and "onsvgload" none of which work.

Is there away to determine if an svg image has actually loaded?

I even tried loading the image using an Image() object and then calling paper.image() - but I  get two calls to the image (instead of using the preloaded image);
    ie:

```
var preload = new Image();
preload.src = imgPath;
preload.addEventListener('load', function () {
    image.path = preload.src;
    //Now load image in raphael - except this still forces the browser to make another call for the image
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `onLoad` event handler works, with one additional line of code:

```
var image = paper.image(path, 0,0,10,10);
var image_node = image.node;
image_node.setAttribute('externalResourcesRequired','true');
image_node.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log("image is loaded!");
})
```

You need to set the `externalResourcesRequired` attribute to true. You may read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ExternalResourcesRequired

Comment: This works for every browser but IE. Any ideas how to make this work in IE?