# How to complete loading of an image ( loaded using Raphael) before executing the rest of the JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael to load an image and then drawing some nodes on the image using raphael. But since the image file is taking some time to load, the nodes are getting loaded before the image. I am looking for suggestions on how to load the image completely before executing the rest of the JS.

```
    var r = Raphael("canvas", 1500,1500);
var attr = {
                //"stroke": "#666",
                "stroke-width": 1,
                "stroke-linejoin": "round",
                "fill": "#000000"
            };
            var t="t-165,-30";
var figure=r.image("images4.png",100,117,600,900); // Loading the image and then more JS follows
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875675/determine-when-an-image-has-loaded-in-svg-with-raphaeljs

Comment: @Neil Thanks !! Thats the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
    //Do your stuff here, the image is loaded.
    delete img;
};
img.setAttribute('src', imageSrc);
```